# Statistical Significance of a single list of dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary in the form: {"Jan": 1, "Feb": 7, etc}

such that every month has an associated number of times an event occurs. I wasn't sure how to tell if on month (or more) is statistically more likely to have that event occur more than any other month. I was confused how to do a t-test (from my limited memory of statistics classes) for this and see which is more significant than the other. I heard of SciPy but that looked like Martian speak to me.

Relatively new to Python, any help on a formula I should use?

Essentially what it boils down to is how can I tell if one key's value is statistically higher than the other keys' values?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out I was wrong! I was looking using the wrong methond. I should have been trying to find outliers instead! I used numpy to find the median and IQR and such, and from there tried to find the outliers.